# Get UTC time from public servers

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

Using FreePascal 3.0.4

Im looking deeply in the web but i can not find nothing usefull (looks like all the threads are for Java), or figure out a way to get a reliable (public and well known servers) and precise (up to milliseconds) UTC time. I do not care if it is via HTTP or TCP, or if i can get it from a server which offers a differente time zone (it could be easily adjustable in my app)

There are some private sites that offers a basic epoch timestamp with a simple URL GET request (example):

```
with TFPHTTPClient.Create(nil) do
  try
    Timestamp := Get('https://api.knownsite.com/api/v1/time');
```

But i need a public and trustable site as source, and even better, many different sources in case one is down.

Thank you.

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/search?q=public+ntp+servers&oq=public+ntp+servers

Comment: Or the NTP client from indy?